# Why does potassium dichromate always reacts in an acidic medium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

On the other hand, potassium manganate reacts in both acidic and alkaline media.

Comment: Slightly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75171/how-do-these-cascade-reactions-work

Answer (score 4):

In an alkaline medium, chromium(VI) exists as potassium chromate instead of potassium dichromate:

$$\ce{Cr2O7^2- + 2OH- <=>> 2CrO4^2- + H2O}$$

[Wikipedia has more information about this equilibrium.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromate_and_dichromate)

Comment: Interesting information @orthocresol. Does this mean that the $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}$ ion have no oxidative abilities despite being in chromium's highest oxidation state?

Comment: No, chromate(VI) is still oxidising